# how to send file from pc to android device with socket coding server side code with delphi

Tags: java, android, delphi, download, delphi-6

I wrote a simple code in Delphi to send and receive wav file between server and client and it works fine. and i wrote a simple code in android to receive file from server but it does not work.

Here is the code:

this my server code in Delphi:

```
procedure TfrmServer.TCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  InputString:String;
  FFilePath,AFullFileName:string;
  AFileStream:TStream;
begin
  FFilePath:='D:\pic1\';
  InputString := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
  if InputString = 'WAV' then begin
     Edit1.Text:=inttostr(strtoint(Edit1.Text)+1);
     Edit2.Text:='connected';

  AFullFileName := FFilePath + 'ad.wav';
  AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFullFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    AThread.Connection.WriteStream(AFileStream, True, True);
    // AThread.Connection.Write(UTF8Encode(TempStr));
  finally
    AFileStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
  AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
end;
```

and client code in delphi work fine:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
FFilePath:string;
AFileStream:TStream;
begin
if TCPClient.Connected then TCPClient.Disconnect;
  TCPClient.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  TCPClient.Port := 8090;
  FFilePath:='.\';
  if FileExists(FFilePath + '1.wav') then
    DeleteFile(FFilePath + '1.wav');
  AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFilePath + '1.wav', fmCreate);
      try
    try
      TCPClient.Connect;
      try
        TCPClient.WriteLn('PIC');
        TCPClient.ReadStream(AFileStream, -1, False);
      finally
        TCPClient.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      AFileStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    DeleteFile(FFilePath + '1.wav');
  end;
end;
```

---

and this my Java code for Android:

```
    final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Socket s = null;
            //   BufferedInputStream get = null;
            try {
                s = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 8090);
                status.setText("74");
                get = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),"UTF-"));
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true);
                if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
                    out.println("WAV");
                    out.flush();
                }
                // receive file
                //  byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
                String SS = "";
                System.out.println("84");

String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "Aidin";
                File path = new File(dir);
                File root = new File(path, "ad.wav");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(root); // destination path and name of file
                  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                System.out.println("92");
              bos=get.read(); 
                bos.flush();
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File received",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // System.out.println(end-start);
                  bos.close();

                fos.flush();
                s.close();
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errorr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  System.exit(0);
            }
       }


        private void Log(String string, String string2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: "It does not work" tells as nothign about how exactly it does not work. Try to specify the protocol specification here, then step by step show how your client implement that protocol, which bytes got send over TCP channel and then in which place your client fails to correctly interprete those bytes.

Comment: But best of all stop that ad-hoc non-standard approach and take advantage of a standard very well defined HTTP protocol. There is a lot of ready-made HTTP server implementations for Delphi and there i sure are a lot of HTTP clients for Java/Android. So you would just take a ready-made component and use it, and if anythign goes wrong you would have a well defined error messages and any HTTP sniffer would tell you what went wrong in network level.

Comment: `TCPClient.WriteLn('PIC');` -  you did not specified Delphi version here and in with `charset` that lien would be posted and which bytes would be terminators after the text (#13 ? #13#10 ? #10 alone ? #0 ? ). Nor did you specified the same for your Java code.

Comment: I am sorry this correct:

Comment: I am sorry this correct: TCPClient.WriteLn('WAV');

Comment: That still does not specify which *bytes* in which order would be sent on TCP/IP network level. You should start with specifying byte-level network protocol, then implementing that protocol in Delphi and Java. Or you can take already specified protocol like HTTP and take ready-made libraries implementing it.

Comment: my delphi version is 6

Comment: I'd expect Java to use UTF-16 letters-to-bytes mapping ("charset") and Delphi 6 using "Latin1" instead. But you have to check the bytes actually transmitted via TCP network, to see if both Delphi and Java correctly implement specifications of your protocol at raw bytes level